# Is there help for Dynamics AX problems or questions?

Tags: discussion, microsoft

Can we ask questions about Dynamics AX on Stack Overflow? Sorry for this generally question, but I don't know where I can ask it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is programming related, you can ask them right here at StackOverflow!

For other topics there are a lot of forums in the wild, a good starting point is:

- [Axapta Communities](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Axapta_Communities)
- [Dynmaics User Group (AX forums)](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=4)

But they are all inferior to StackOverflow!

Comment: StackOverflow really rocks :p

Answer (score 1):

The official Microsoft forums for Dynamics AX are located at

https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33.aspx

You will need a live id to post.

Comment: Already have one, thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! ;)

There are already lots of them answered, just browse the AX tags on the right menu.

Comment: nice, thank God I'm not the only one who asks about AX :p